# Handling Rc pointers correctly in a parent/children tree

Tags: rust, reference, weak-references

#### Needs

- A container holds two collections: `Parent` instances and `Child` instances; their items can be searched by name;
- A child can return a reference to its parent;
- A parent can search its children by name and return one of them by reference;
- A `Child` is read-only after creation, but new children or parents can be added at runtime;

#### Implementation

To do it, I choose to use `Rc<RefCell<...>>` and `Weak<RefCell<...>>` because I didn't find any other decent solution (unless maybe raw pointers):

- in the container I store strong references to `Parent` and `Child` instances in order to be sure they will be alive during all the container's life,
- and other references (`Parent`->`Child` and `Child`->`Parent`) are stored as weak references, in order to avoid cyclic references.

#### Questions

- Concerning the way of handling references, is there a better way to do it?
- Assuming that no reference at all will be kept outside the container's scope, is there a way to simplify it?
  Indeed, by looking at the last test, you can see that readability is getting a bit hard, just for a simple request like "Give me the name of ...". And beyond readability, I wonder if this does not have a runtime cost that could be avoided.

*Note*: The code could be improved by using `HashMap` instead of `Vec`, but my question is not dealing about this.

````
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::rc::{Weak, Rc};
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Child {
    name: String,
    parent: Weak<RefCell<Parent>>,
}

impl Child {
    fn new(name: &str, parent: &Rc<RefCell<Parent>>) -> Child {
        Child {
            name: name.to_string(),
            parent: Rc::downgrade(parent),
        }
    }

    fn parent(&self) -> &Weak<RefCell<Parent>> {
        &self.parent
    }

    fn strong_parent(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<Parent>> {
        // As far as I understand, unwrap() should never panic as long as the container is still
        // alive:
        self.parent.upgrade().unwrap()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parent {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<Weak<RefCell<Child>>>,
}

impl Parent {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Parent {
        Parent {
            name: name.to_string(),
            children: vec![],
        }
    }

    fn add_child(&mut self, child: &Rc<RefCell<Child>>) {
        self.children.push(Rc::downgrade(child));
    }

    fn child(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&Weak<RefCell<Child>>> {
        self.children.iter()
            .find(|c| c.upgrade().unwrap().borrow().name == name)
    }

    fn strong_child(&self, name: &str) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<Child>>> {
        self.children.iter()
            .map(|c| c.upgrade().unwrap())
            .find(|c| c.borrow().name == name)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Child>>>,
    parents:  Vec<Rc<RefCell<Parent>>>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn new() -> Container {
        Container {
            children: vec![],
            parents: vec![],
        }
    }

    pub fn add_child(&mut self, name: &str, parent: &Rc<RefCell<Parent>>) -> &Rc<RefCell<Child>> {
        if self.child(name).is_some() {
            panic!(format!("Child '{}' already exists.", name));
        }
        let child = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Child::new(name, parent)));
        parent.borrow_mut().add_child(&child);
        self.children.push(child);
        self.children.last().unwrap()
    }

    pub fn add_parent(&mut self, name: &str) -> &Rc<RefCell<Parent>> {
        if self.parent(name).is_some() {
            panic!(format!("Parent '{}' already exists.", name));
        }
        let parent = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Parent::new(name)));
        self.parents.push(parent);
        self.parents.last().unwrap()
    }

    pub fn parent(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&Rc<RefCell<Parent>>> {
        self.parents.iter()
            .find(|p| p.borrow().name == name)
    }

    pub fn child(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&Rc<RefCell<Child>>> {
        self.children.iter()
            .find(|c| c.borrow().name == name)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    #[allow(unused_variables)]
    fn simple_test() {
        let mut container = Container::new();
        let p1 = container.add_parent("parent1").clone();
        let p1_c1 = container.add_child("parent1-child1", &p1).clone();
        let p1_c2 = container.add_child("parent1-child2", &p1).clone();

        // Here are tests as well as examples of how I would you use this code:

        // Get the parent of parent1-child1;
        assert_eq!(p1_c1.borrow().strong_parent().borrow().name, "parent1");

        // Get a child from parent1:
        assert_eq!(
            p1.borrow().strong_child("parent1-child2").unwrap().borrow().name,
            "parent1-child2"
        );
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since the child is read-only after creation, couldn't you use `Child` instead of `RefCell<Child>`?

Comment: This is a nice and appropriate simplication, thank you